# How to hide an inner html thats coming from CMS

Tags: jquery, html, content-management-system

I have the following div #menu. The contents within the div gets populated from a CMS.

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a dataid="1111" title="Home" href="/">Home</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><a dataid="24693" title="Items">Items</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a dataid="24770" title="Product" title=My-Products">
        My Products
        <span class="sf-sub-indicator "> »</span>
      </a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

All the `<ul>` tags are populate by a CMS. I want to hide the `dataid="24770"` link in 'My Products' from the menu div when the page loads and then when a user logs in My products should show.

Can you please advise me as to how to go about hiding this? I am not sure how to detect it since it's coming from a CMS. If I can get it to hide as a starting point I can then figure out on how to show it based on a condition. Thank you.

Comment: `$('#menu a[dataid="24770"]').closest('ul').hide()`

Comment: I'd suggest doing this server side. The link will still be visible in the HTML when not logged in, so this is about as insecure as it gets.

Comment: $('#menu a[dataid="24770"]').closest('ul').remove();

Comment: Instead of hide you may remove it from HTML DOM

Comment: Shouldnt populate it on the first time if it is not related menu item.

Comment: Thanks.do you think there is a way to get the dataid dynamically instead of passing it the fixed value?